# RANGE vs HASH partitioning for storage by Month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-8.0

For my Table, I need to partition based on `created` **timestamp** field by **Month**.

I am evaluating the following two approaches:

- **RANGE**

  ```
    ALTER TABLE my_table
        PARTITION BY RANGE ( MONTH(created) ) (
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
        PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
        PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
        PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
        PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
        PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
        PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
        PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (13)
    );
  ```
- **HASH**

  ```
    ALTER TABLE my_table 
        PARTITION BY HASH((YEAR(created) * 100) + MONTH(created)) 
        PARTITIONS 13;
  ```

***Use case:***

My use case is that I want to archive by month, for the month which has crosses 1 year. For example, if the current month is july-2020, then the parition corresponsing to july-2019 would be archived, also the secondary use case is the partition pruning to improve the performance as most of the queries include this timestamp column.

**Why 13 partitions in the HASH one?**

*As stated above, I will be archiving the 13th month from current month.*

For this use case, which approach would suit better? As far as I understand, when I'm defining it by RANGE, I have the directly control on which data goes into which partition, and in case of HASH, it would be defined by MySQL HASH function (mod) and that will make things difficult to identify the "over the year" partition and archive it specifically.

Or is there any totally different approach for this use case?

Comment: You should make sure to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html, specifically "Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a DATE or DATETIME column when the partitioning expression uses the YEAR() or TO_DAYS() function." This means your use of `MONTH()` won't be able to use partition pruning, so the partitioning won't help query optimization.

Comment: @BillKarwin I was evaluating my queries using the `EXPLAIN` , and it easily identified the exact partition in which the data lies, which means to me that pruning is happening. Am I understanding it wrong ?

Comment: if you want to partition by month, why did you include "year" value into hash partitioning?

Comment: @mangusta HASH needs a function to return non negative integer value. The expression: `(YEAR(created) * 100) + MONTH(created)`   resolves to something like: 202007 , for the current year-month, which is quite helpful to maintain partiotions year+month wise. If I just make it month (like in the `RANGE` partition) then it will re-use the existing partition.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think you are right. using `MONTH()` pruning is not happening when i use statement like: `EXPLAIN select * from my_table where created < "2020-05-14" AND created > "2020-05-11" \G ;`   Ideally it should have looked in just one partition for May, but it is looking up into all the partitions. And when I tried at `YEAR()` level, it is doing proper pruning.   For month, it is doing the pruning when only when `=` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITION BY HASH` is useless. Period.
`PARTITION BY RANGE` can be useful if you want to purge "old" data.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

What will you do next January?

Show me your `SELECTs` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I'll help you optimize the `INDEXes` for a non-partitioned version.  It will run as fast or faster than you think your schema.

**More**

- `BY HASH` is useless when you have a "range".  The Optimizer will always pick all partitions, thereby slowing down the query.  (This flaw applies to most partitioning methods.)
- If you always use `WHERE month=constant`, you may as well have the column `month` early in indexes.  `MONTH(date_col) = constant` is a different matter.  (I have not thought through all the implications.  Let's see your queries.)
- As a general rule, you can build an index on a non-partitioned table that will provide the equivalent functionality as partition pruning.  (The link lists only 4 exceptions to the rule.  I've spent a decade looking for more use cases.)  *Correlary:*  When switching to/from partitioning, all the indexes, including the `PRIMARY KEY`, should be redesigned.
- One of my use cases is to use "transportable tablespaces" to archive one whole partition.  You *might* be able to use that with `BY HASH`; it's rather clear how to do it with `BY RANGE`.
- The main focus of my blog is to explain `DROPping` (or 'transporting') the oldest of a 13-month partitions and `REORGANIZE` to get a new "month" (or other time range).

Comment: Interestingly, I have landed on your pages mysql.rjweb.org many times, when I get into depth of SQL. :)

Comment: And to answer your question `What will you do next January?` : I will archive data of last year's january and then reuse that partition OR create a new partition, whichever is better.

Comment: I want to understand what made you conclude that : PARTITION BY HASH is useless.